# Applescript - append text to a logfile in newline

Tags: applescript

I am trying to append a result of a variable to a text file based on a condition in Applescript and I need some help.
The LogFile.txt file should be of format

URLNAME : Blocked

URLNAME : Blocked

URLNAME : Allowed

My question is , how can i keep updating to the same LogFile.txt file newline. That is each time I append the text, it should get written in a next line. I am using the below code to accomplish

```
set this_story to "URLNAME : Blocked"
set this_file to (((path to desktop folder) as string) & "LOGFILE")
my write_to_file(this_story, this_file, true)

on write_to_file(this_data, target_file, append_data)
try
    set the target_file to the target_file as string
    set the open_target_file to open for access file target_file with write permission
    write this_data to the open_target_file starting at eof
    close access the open_target_file
    return true
on error
    try
        close access file target_file
    end try
    return false
end try
end write_to_file
```

I thought that the "starting at eof" on the 5th line in handler should have done the trick but is not helping.

Comment: [Answer](https://www.google.com/search?name=f&hl=en&q=applescript+append+file)

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but when i try to set it as eof , the text is not getting written in the next line.

Comment: can you edit your question with the relevant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just change your string to include newlines like this...

```
set this_story to "URLNAME : Blocked

"
```

You can also use `\n` in your string to indicate a new line but the editor has a habit to expand it like in the example above.

The `write` command does not automatically add new lines to data written. It is up to you to do that.

EDIT:

This article has some interesting information regarding line endings on OSX/Applescript Editor.

http://latenightsw.com/sd4/help/indexfolder/referencfolder/faqfolder/lineendings.html

Comment: Your link no longer works.  Perhaps this is helpful:

https://latenightsw.com/carriage-returns-linefeeds/